# handlebars +=,-= if condition met

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I've been searching the net net for a while now trying to find a way to aggregate json array values with handlebars using +=, or -= if the condition is met. however i can't seem to find any guidelines on how to properly do so. can anyone guide me on how to convert this iteration into a handlebars helper?

```
var table = $("#table tbody");
$.getJSON("front-end/ajax/bethistory.php", function(data) {
    var value = 0;
    $.each(data, function(a, b) {
        if (b.action == "win") {
            value += parseFloat(b.coins);
        } else if (b.action == "lose") {
            value -= parseFloat(b.coins);
        }
        var tbody = $("<tr/>").append($("<td/>").html(b.action), $("<td/>").html(value))
        table.append(tbody);
    });
});
```

something like this?

```
var value = 0;  
Handlebars.registerHelper("this_val", function(a,b) {

        if (a == "win") {
            value += parseFloat(b);
        } else if (a ==  "lose") {
            value -= parseFloat(b);
        }

        return value;

});
```

Comment: can't understand your question. You talking about this?
 value += (b.action==="win"?: 
                           parseFloat(b.coins):
                           parseFloat(b.coins) * (-1)
                          );

Answer (score 1):

for anyone who needs this. i was able to figure it out  [thanks to this post](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-beginners-guide-to-handlebars/)

```
    Handlebars.registerHelper("compute", function(array, options) {

        var new_array = "",
        value = 0,
        count = array.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            var coins = Number(array[i]['coins']),
            action = array[i]['action'];

            if (action == "win") {
                if (coins > 0) {
                    value += coins;
                }
            } else if (action == "lose") {
                if (coins > 0) {
                    value -= coins;
                }
            }

            array[i]['running'] = value;
            new_array += options.fn(array[i]);
        }
        return new_array;
    });
```